# Plot with Color Data as Third Coordinate of Ordered Pairs

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

Suppose I have a data set

```
data={{0,0,-1},{0,1,-0.5},{1,1,0},{2,1,0.5},{2,2,1}};
```

where the first two coordinates are x and y values, and the third is input for the color gradient function

```
crgrad[x_] := Blend[{{-1, Blue},{0, Black}, {1, Red}}, x];
```

What is the correct way to plot the data points and have each point be its corresponding color? I have already tried

```
dataPlt = Graphics[{Point[{#1, #2}], ColorFunction -> (crgrad[#3])} & @@@ data];
```

I also want to incorporate

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> False
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Graphics[{crgrad[#3], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ data]`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have to use `ColorFunction`, you can use

```
Graphics[{crgrad[#3], PointSize[.05], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
Graphics[{PointSize[.05], Point[{#1, #2}, VertexColors -> crgrad[#3]]} & @@@ data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
ListPlot[Style[{#, #2}, crgrad[#3], PointSize[.05]] & @@@ data, 
 Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> .2, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For some reason I could not get the method to work after reading your comment, but it now works brilliantly. Thank you.

Comment: @S2167, thank you for the accept.